# xsl regex variable which has a url

Tags: xslt

my xsl variable has the value as below

```
<xsl:variable name="url">
        <xsl:value-of select="'http://1.2.34.4:70/Anything/uri'"/>
      </xsl:variable>
```

I need to replace the ip address and port combination part with a name - abcd.com, then store it in another variable. So the variable will have the value 'http://abcd.com/Anything/uri'. How can I do this. Do I have to use regex. The variable url can start with https as well, plus the uri can have any number os slashes. ie instead of /Anything/uri it can have /uri or /Anything/other/uri as well

Comment: Do you use XSLT 2.0? XSLT 1.0 does not have regular expression support. Also note that your code can be shortened to `<xsl:variable name="url" select="'http://1.2.34.4:70/Anything/uri'"/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vReplacement" select="'abcd.com'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="vUrl" select="'http://1.2.34.4:70/Anything/uri'"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vReplaced">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($vUrl,'//'), '//')"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="concat($vReplacement, '/')"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after($vUrl,'//'),'/')"/>
     </xsl:variable>

     "<xsl:copy-of select="$vReplaced"/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (not used), sets the variable `$vReplaced` to the wanted, correct value and copies its content to the output**:

```
"http://abcd.com/Anything/uri"
```

**Explanation**: Proper use of **[`substring-before()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-before)**, **[`substring-after()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-after)** and [**`concat()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-concat).